# Automatically adding the date/time to a cell when another cell is updated

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have the below code that I need to edit to look at the whole column D and if Yes is selected then will put the date next to it in column E. However I can't get anything to work.

````
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now
 End If

End Sub```
````

Comment: The code works for me. Bear in mind that it must be in the worksheet's code module. If it's in a standard code module it won't work. Apart from that, the range "D:D" appears a little large at 1.4 million cells. But if you really mean to be so sweeping then `If Target.Column = 4 Then Target.Offset.Value = Now()` will work just the same.

Comment: Do you know what I should be doing to make it only return date if Yes is in column D?

Comment: Sorry! That should be (must be!) `If Target.Column = 4 Then Target.Offset(0,1).Value = Now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below the requirement is that Target's column is "D" and its value is "yes".

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If (.Column = 4) And (StrComp(.Value, "yes", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
           .Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

`vbTextCompare` compares the value with "yes" case insensitive, meaning "yes", "YES" or "Yes" will all be considered a match. If you want to insist on case sensitive comparison specify `vbBinaryCompare`.